# SSRS - Producing a report that is not dynamic in size

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting

I want to build a report that is completely static in size and shape.  I'm attempting to mimic a hand-entered report that someone in my organization has been building from a word doc for years.

The critical piece appears to be fixing the number of rows that are produced in the various Table grids that fill the page.  I would like them to always contain a set number of rows, whether data is present or not.  It would seem that if I can just fix the size my tables, then all the other elements will not be forced to move because of stretching repeater sections.

All my grids are backed by stored procedures, so I'm open to SQL tricks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry i did miss-read the question.

If you know how many rows you need to return (say 20) maybe you could pad some bogus info into your records returned from the stored procedure. You might be able to count the records your query has returned before you send them back, and if you have less than 20 add some bogus ones to the record set, put something like 'NonDisp' or something in them.

Then in the report put an iif statement into the cells that checks for this bogus info, if it is found change the cell to display nothing, otherwise show the valid values

Comment: It's not the columns that I'm trying to control, it's the number of rows.  To mimic the legacy report, each table-grid needs to have to be a set number of rows, and always be that number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but perhaps a workaround you might consider: perhaps you can insert a page break after the table grids that have dynamic sizes, so that all elements that follow it have a fixed position (relative to the top of the page).

Comment: Nice tip, but when printed, won't the report break into multiple pages?

Comment: @John Cocktoastan - Yes it will, so it is not a direct solution to your problem, but at least you have more control over the position of the elements that follow the dynamically sized table. 
By the way, what editor do you use for designing the report, the Business Intelligence Dev Studio?

Comment: Yes, I'm on BIDS 2005.  For now I'm just writing the SQL in such a way that my procs always produce the desired number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent group to tablix with =Ceiling((RowNumber(Nothing)) / 10000) expression. (10000 or whatever is required no. of rows)

In page break properties of group, check box for insert break between groups, leave the bottom boxes un-checked.

Optionally, we may chose to set hidden property true for text boxes added because of new parent group.

In tablix properties, check box for "Keep together on one page".